# NSIS registry:Write not writing all of the value needed

Tags: registry, installation, nsis

I have this line of code

```
${registry::Write} "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\autodocedithandler\shell\open\command" "" "$PROGRAMFILES32\AutoDocEdit\AutoDocEdit.exe $\"%1$\"" "REG_EXPAND_SZ" $R0
```

When I run the installer and check the registry afterwards I see that only the '%1' has been entered to the registry as the value - the path before did not make it.

Any reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by using a definition for the folder

```
!define DefaultAutoDocEditFolder "$PROGRAMFILES32\AutoDocEdit\AutoDocEdit.exe"
```

and later using like this

```
${registry::Write} "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\autodocedithandler\shell\open\command" "" '${DefaultAutoDocEditFolder} "%1"' "REG_EXPAND_SZ" $R0
```

Hope this solution helps someone else.

Comment: There is no reason for this to work any better, defines are expanded as the first step in the compilation process. And even if it works, your quotes are still wrong, you should quote the path. `!define DefaultAutoDocEditFolder '"$PROGRAMFILES32\AutoDocEdit\AutoDocEdit.exe"'`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it does not like the quotes.

Try

```
${registry::Write} "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\autodocedithandler\shell\open\command" "" '"$PROGRAMFILES32\AutoDocEdit\AutoDocEdit.exe" "%1"' "REG_EXPAND_SZ" $R0
```

You don't need to use this plug-in to write this string, you could just use `WriteRegStr`. There is nothing to expand (Explorer/shell32 expands %1 internally) so you don't need it to be the expanding string type.

Comment: I tried with and without the quotes in many various ways and none worked.

Comment: Could be a bug in the plug-in perhaps, I'll take a look at it. Either way, there is no reason to use this plug-in to write this string, just use the normal NSIS instruction.

Comment: Both your code in your question and my code works perfectly for me.